# Why isn't my custom 404 page being redirected to in the case of 404 errors on a ColdFusion site on IIS 7.5? How can I fix it?

Tags: iis, coldfusion, http-status-code-404

Edit: I figured it out a few minutes after posting this question. See my answer below.

This site I'm working on is built with ColdFusion and the web server is IIS 7.5. I have created a custom 404 page, /error.cfm, and I have tried to add code to the web.config file so that when a user gets a 404 error, they're redirected to error.cfm as the custom 404 page. But it's not working at all, it's giving me the default "IIS 7.5 Detailed Error - 404.0 - Not Found" page.

Can someone look at my web.config code and tell me if there's anything wrong with it, or if I can fix this custom 404 page in some way?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <configuration>
        <system.webServer>
            <rewrite>
                <rules>
                    <rule name="Redirect to WWW" stopProcessing="true">
                        <match url=".*" />
                        <conditions>
                            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example.com$" />
                        </conditions>
                        <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
                    </rule>
                </rules>
            </rewrite>
            <httpErrors>
                <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
                <error statusCode="404" path="/error.cfm" responseMode="Redirect" />
            </httpErrors>
            <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
        </system.webServer> 
    </configuration>
```

As you can see, I have also put in a redirect for all non-www links to www. I'm not sure if this could be interfering with the custom 404 page in any way, but I figured I'd mention it just in case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it. I had to go into cpanel, look for "IIS Settings", find "Custom Errors" and set the URL in there. But it didn't work if I put in http://www.example.com/error.cfm, I had to put in http://example.com/error.cfm (without the www).

Comment: Glad you got it working. If you are curious, you should be able to look at the new web.config file that was created and see how it differs from what you had. Also I don't usually include the domain at all when specifying the custom error handler URL.  I just specify it with a relative URL from the web root.  `/error.cfm` in your case.